# Postgresql : insert record using trigger

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
 id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('userseq'::regclass)
 ........
)

CREATE TABLE History
(
 userid integer,
 createdat timestamp with time zone
)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recordcreatetime()
      RETURNS trigger AS
        $BODY$
        BEGIN
                NEW.createdAt = NOW();
                RETURN NEW;
        END;
        $BODY$
          LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
          COST 100;
```

User and History has one-one relationship. How i can insert new record in History table before creating new user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recordcreatetime()
  RETURNS trigger 
language plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO History values(new.id,NOW() );
 RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

and write trigger statement as

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_hist
BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE function  recordcreatetime() ;
```